# NodeJS request with range does not work with HTML5 video

Tags: node.js, typescript, vue.js, video-streaming, html5-video

I have implemented a request using nodejs to serve video with range support, backend looks like this:

```
  import { createReadStream, statSync } from 'fs';
  

  const stats = statSync(path);

  const range = request.headers.range;
  const parts = range.replace(/bytes=/, '').split('-');
  
  const start = parseInt(parts[0], 10);
  let end = parts[1] ? parseInt(parts[1], 10) : start + 10 * 1024 ** 2;

  if (end > stats.size) {
    end = stats.size;
  }

  const stream = createReadStream(path, {
    emitClose: false,
    flags: 'r',
    start,
    end,
  });

  reply.status(206).headers({
    'content-type': 'video/webm',
    'accept-ranges': 'bytes',
    'content-length': end - start,
    'content-range': `bytes ${start}-${end}/${stats.size}`,
  }).send(stream);
```

This is a [fastify](https://www.fastify.io/docs/latest/) api, my frontend looks like this

```
<video :src="videoUrl" @timeupdate="playProgress" @error="videoError" @loadedmetadata="videoDataLoaded" @ended="videoEnd" ref="video" />
```

And this is a vue web app, now the problem is, video element sends only two requests with ranges as below then throws error `PIPELINE_ERROR_READ: FFmpegDemuxer: data source error`, the requests:

```
range: bytes=0-
range: bytes=147456000-
```

The surprising thing is I only return 10mb of data per request so the second request is way off. This has been driving me crazy and I don't know what am missing, any help would be highly appreciated at this point, I have already wasted alot of time on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
'content-length': end - start + 1,
```

and this

```
let end = parts[1] ? parseInt(parts[1], 10) : stat.size - 1;
```

instead of

```
let end = parts[1] ? parseInt(parts[1], 10) : start + 10 * 1024 ** 2;
```

Comment: Both `net::ERR_CONTENT_LENGTH_MISMATCH 206 (Partial Content)` and `MediaError {code: 2, message: "PIPELINE_ERROR_READ: FFmpegDemuxer: data source error"}`

Comment: and this   `let end = parts[1] ? parseInt(parts[1], 10) : stat.size - 1;`  instead of  `let end = parts[1] ? parseInt(parts[1], 10) : start + 10 * 1024 ** 2;`

Comment: Ok not the solution I was hoping for but that worked

Comment: Btw this solution works great, thanks, might wanna update the answer so i can accept